# How to make sure views dont overlap when placed in a Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, overlapping

I use a `RelativeLayout` to place views using `LayoutParams` and setting the top (y coordinate) and left margin (x coordinate).  How can I make sure that when I place views using absolute position that none of them overlap each other?  I do run into overlapping issues in some spots and the only work around I have right now is to scale up the y values.

Here's my code to place the views:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.leftMargin = x;
lp.topMargin = y;
```

then once I create the view I place it in the layout at the correct spot:

```
if(field.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("label"))
{
  CSLabel label = (CSLabel) field;
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(label.getText()));

  rscroll.addView(tv, lp);
}
```

Here's a picture of what happens though sometimes:

[image]

The textview and radiogroup in this case are overlapping.  Are there any ways to fix overlapping programmatically?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either restrict the radio button to stay below the text view or restrict the text view to stay above the radio button.

Use the addRule(int, int) method of layout params and RelativeLayout.BELOW or RelativeLayout.ABOVE.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int,int)

Answer (score 1):

You don't most likely want to use x/y coordinates to set the position of your views, instead use alignTop / alignBottom layout parameters to set the position relative to other view, which will ensure that no overlapping is going to happen!

Also please consider using different layouts, such as LinearLayout with Vertical orieantation, its much more efficient in simple cases such as yours.

Also please consider defining layout in XML instead of Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Use align_top, layout_below and other properties provided by Relative Layout to align your views.I would also recommend you to align your layouts via XML and not programmatically.

Read this for more info on relative layouts http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html